# How to create <th> tag only once

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a function, that creates a cells in table automatically. It takes information from array and puts it to the cell. But I don't know how to create a header cell for this table with a function. Is there a way to create a whole table with one function?
My HTML is next:

```
<div id="table"> 
   <details>
       <summary class="summary">
           day 1
       </summary>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>count1 </th>
                    <th>count2</th>
                    <th>count3</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="createTable"></tr>
            </table>
   </details>
</div>
```

And function is next:

```
function addTable(array) { 
    var check_value = array;     
    for(var count in check_value){
        var node = document.createElement('tr');   
        node.innerHTML = '<td class ="tdtable">'+check_value[count][0]+'</td>'+
                         '<td class ="tdtable">'+check_value[count][1]+'</td>'+
                         '<td class ="tdtable">'+check_value[count][2]+'</td>'+
                         '<td class ="tdtable">'+check_value[count][3]+'</td>';
        document.getElementById('createTable').appendChild(node);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a function that call 2 different functions, one to create rows, one to create header

Comment: Right before your loop when you create the TR node, create a <thead> node, append your headers within a new <tr>, add <th>title</th>, etc. close the TR and prepend it before appending your looped node; just one approach - better deal with it before the loop begins in a single function rather than two

Comment: why ignore the existing documentation, when you will have to read the same answers here anyway? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow

Answer (score 0):

how about you add that in another tag called  and then in javascript update the innerHTML by "currentHTML" + new th tag or you can do by the append method

```
var tr = document.getElementById('table').tHead.children[0],
    th = document.createElement('th');
th.innerHTML = "This is the new th";
tr.appendChild(th);
```